# Elasticsearch shingle token filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch, shingles

I'm trying this on a local 1.7.5 elasticsearch installation

```
http://localhost:9200/_analyze?filter=shingle&tokenizer=keyword&text=alkis stack
```

I see this

```
{
   "tokens":[
      {
         "token":"alkis stack",
         "start_offset":0,
         "end_offset":11,
         "type":"word",
         "position":1
      }
   ]
}
```

And I expected to see something like this

```
{
   "tokens":[
      {
         "token":"alkis stack",
         "start_offset":0,
         "end_offset":11,
         "type":"word",
         "position":1
      },
      {
         "token":"stack alkis",
         "start_offset":0,
         "end_offset":11,
         "type":"word",
         "position":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Update

```
{
  "number_of_shards": 2,
  "number_of_replicas": 0,
  "analysis": {
    "char_filter": {
      "map_special_chars": {
        "type": "mapping",
        "mappings": [
          "- => \\u0020",
          ". => \\u0020",
          "? => \\u0020",
          ", => \\u0020",
          "` => \\u0020",
          "' => \\u0020",
          "\" => \\u0020"
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "permutate_fullname": {
        "type": "shingle",
        "max_shingle_size": 4,
        "min_shingle_size": 2,
        "output_unigrams": true,
        "token_separator": " ",
        "filler_token": "_"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "fullname_analyzer_search": {
        "char_filter": [
          "map_special_chars"
        ],
        "filter": [
          "asciifolding",
          "lowercase",
          "trim"
        ],
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "keyword"
      },
      "fullname_analyzer_index": {
        "char_filter": [
          "map_special_chars"
        ],
        "filter": [
          "asciifolding",
          "lowercase",
          "trim",
          "permutate_fullname"
        ],
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to test like this

```
http://localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_analyze?analyzer=fullname_analyzer_index&text=alkis stack
```

Comment: No, it is working as expected. And using `keyword` will not split the two terms btw. What do you want to accomplish, though?

Comment: I posted the entire analyzer. I want to normalize a field (fullname) and make permutations in order to make a fuzzy search in the end. Basically I want to take `Andrei Stefan` and normalize it. Then make permutations `andrei stefan` and `stefan andrei`.

Comment: The reason I'm using keyword instead of standard or whitespace, is because I want to keep the entire fullname as one token. But when the permutations are created, I need it to use whitespace which is indeed what's configured.

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't think that permutations are possible with terms out-of-the-box. Shingles are a variation on this but they don't switch places of terms. I'm still wondering the real use-case for this. You mentioned _fuzzy_ search, but what you want to actually search (terms only, match, query_string etc)?

Comment: For example, can't you use `multi_match` or even `term`?

Comment: First of all I'm new to elasticsearch, if this doesn't make sense to you, then maybe what I'm thinking is not possible or not optimal. I was thinking of creating these permutations so the searching with `andrei stefan` and `stefan andrei` will produce the same result. What I've understood reading about term and match is that they are similar, but differ on the fact the term is not analyzed. So either I do the analysis in elasticsearch and use match or do the normalisation of the query on the client and use term. I was thinking of using query string since I don't want to have multiple terms.

Comment: If I use the standard tokenizer and I have indexed `Andrei Stefan`. Then by using a match query and searching for `Andrei Foo`, then I will get a match. Is that correct (if yes, then that's what I'm trying to avoid, if no then I've misunderstood something)? What I'm trying to do is to build a simple name search functionality.

Comment: Simple name search should be difficult and I doubt you need that permutations thing. What are the requirements of this search? (exact match, lowercase/uppercase matters?, fuzzy?....) Start by creating a list of the things you'd like the search to do and what to match given certain input data.

Comment: It will be fuzzy, lowercase everything since case shouldn't matter. I need to use asciifolding in order to remove accents, they shouldn't matter either. I believe I've got all this covered with the analyzer as is. Any characters like dash, comma etc. (e.g. Jr. ) shouldn't matter either. The only thing I haven't done yet is the order of name and surname. That shouldn't matter either. Since this can't be done in es, with shingles, then I can just use a query with an or operator and permutate on query param on the client side.

Comment: Do you have separate fields for first name and last name?

Comment: Nope... That would make my life easier.

Comment: And you don't have control over the mapping this way? I'm assuming you just have a `name` field? And what does the user search? A full name or separate strings?

Comment: Basically I have the fields in the db. Fullname, Surname, Firstname. The problem is that the query param is a fullname. It is not separated. So I need to check against the fullname (and the lastname with the same analyzer, but not the firstname). Checking the lastname will ensure that I will get results where only the last name is provided as a query param. And checking the fullname instead of the first name will ensure that I will not get Alkis Foo and Alkis Bar, when I searched with alkis foo. I can't try to separate the query param because that's a difficult road on its own

Comment: Just for clarity, I don't want or better say I don't care, to get results when the query is only the firstname.

Comment: Hm... index first name and last name in two separate fields in ES, just as you have them in the DB. The text received as query can be analyzed (`match` does it for example, `query_string` does it). And there are ways to search both fields at the same time with all the **terms** in the search string. I think you are over-complicating the use case with single name in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index first name and last name in **two separate fields** in ES, just as you have them in the DB. The text received as query can be analyzed (`match` does it for example, `query_string` does it). And there are ways to search both fields at the same time with all the terms in the search string. I think you are over-complicating the use case with single name in one go and creating names permutations at indexing time.